# Check nas tabelas que aparecem no meu primeiro DBGrid

Tags: mysql, delphi

Segue o código:

```pascal
var
  i : integer;
begin
  i := 0;

  DataModule1.ZConnection1.Database :=  edtDB.Text;
  DataModule1.ZConnection1.HostName := edtLocal.Text;
  DataModule1.ZConnection1.User := 'root';

  DataModule1.ZQuery1.Close;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM '+edtDB.Text);
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.Open;

  while not DataModule1.ZQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    inc(i);
    DataModule1.ZQuery2.Close;
    DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
    DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('CHECK TABLE ' + edtDB.Text + '.' +
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' + edtDB.Text).asString);
    DataModule1.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;
    DataModule1.ZQuery1.Next;
  end;
```

*O que quero, é que até o fim das linhas encontradas no `showTables`(que está situado no primeiro dbgrid), o meu check leia todas as linhas **(Com as tables)** e consequentemente dê um `check` em outro dbgrid, como faço isso?*

**Código atualizado**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não posso ter certeza sem ver quem é o dbShow, porém tente o seguinte:

```pascal
DataModule1.ZQuery1.Close;
DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM '+edtDB.Text);
DataModule1.ZQuery1.Open;
while not DataModule1.ZQuery1.Eof do
begin
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Close;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('CHECK TABLES '+dbShow.Fields[i].Text);
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.Next;
end;
```

---

Após saber nos comentários que esta função deve mostrar o resultado da ZQuery2 em um dbgrid, segue alteração:

```pascal
DataModule1.ZQuery1.Close;
DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM '+edtDB.Text);
DataModule1.ZQuery1.Open;
DataModule1.ZQuery1.First;
Parametro := '';
Parametro := edtDB.Text + '.' + DataModule1.ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' + edtDB.Text).asString);
if DataModule1.ZQuery1.RecordCount > 1 then //Substitua pelo comando de quantidade de registros
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.Next;
while not DataModule1.ZQuery1.Eof do
begin
  Parametro := Parametro + ', ' + edtDB.Text + '.' + DataModule1.ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' + edtDB.Text).asString);
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.Next;
end;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Close;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Sql.Text := 'Check tables ' + Parametro;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Open;
```

Se você debugar o while, o parâmetro criado monta a lista de tabelas a serem visualizadas no comando Check Tables. Portanto Parametro = Parametro(todas as tabelas que voce fez até agora) + , + nova tabela a ser checada.

Comment: qual seria o comando de quantidade de registros que tu comentou?

Comment: ele está dando um erro de Syntax SQL.

Comment: Depende do seu componente. Em um `TClientDataSet` por exemplo é `CDS.RecordCount`

Comment: Coloca um breakpoint no  `DataModule1.ZQuery2.Open;` e me passa o valor de   `DataModule1.ZQuery2.Sql.Text `

Comment: ele conseguiu fazer um teste, o problema estava no próprio parâmetro, `',' + ` tinha isto a mais, ele ta fazendo a checagem toda, mais nao mostra tudo.

Comment: Não mostra tudo porque você tirou a virgula! Coloque `Parametro := Parametro + ', ' + edtDB.Text + '.' + DataModule1.ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' + edtDB.Text).asString);`

Comment: Funcionou, deu tudo certo!!!

Comment: Editei com a explicação do while. Quanto ao repair, é uma outra história (quase)completamente diferente.