# Repair nas tabelas Checkadas

Tags: mysql, delphi

Segue o código:

```
status := DataModule1.ZQuery2.FieldByName('Msg_text').AsString;
  while not DataModule1.ZQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    if status <> 'OK' then
    begin
      DataModule1.ZQuery3.Close;
      DataModule1.ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
      DataModule1.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('Repair tables ' + Parametro);
      DataModule1.ZQuery3.Open;
      ShowMessage(DataModule1.ZQuery3.Sql.Text);
    end
    else
    begin
    DataModule1.ZQuery1.Next;
    end;
  end;
```

*Com a ajuda do Filipe.Fonseca, consegui realizar a checagem dos itens, segue abaixo o link.*

[Check nas tabelas que aparecem no meu primeiro DBGrid](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16532/check-nas-tabelas-que-aparecem-no-meu-primeiro-dbgrid/16537?noredirect=1#comment30683_16537)

Apenas quero que caso o `Msg_Text`, não seja OK, ele realize o `Repair`.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mais uma vez você está se enrolando com as Queries. Defina nomes *"amigáveis"* para não dar next na Query errada, por exemplo `QryTabelas`, `QryStatus`, etc.

Tente dessa forma:

```pascal
while not DataModule1.ZQuery2.Eof do
begin
  status := DataModule1.ZQuery2.FieldByName('Msg_text').AsString;
  if status <> 'OK' then
  begin
    DataModule1.ZQuery3.Close;
    DataModule1.ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
    DataModule1.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('Repair tables ' + Parametro);
    DataModule1.ZQuery3.ExecSQL;
    ShowMessage(DataModule1.ZQuery3.Sql.Text);
  end
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Next;
end;
```

Comment: caramba cara, está certo novamente, eu estava realizando o while com o do ZQuery1. e nao com o 2. Mas ta show! Deu certo. Assim que corromper um banco de dados vou testar direitinho e te digo.